# Find at what percentile the average of each key lies on in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, percentile

I have a dataframe with columns as values, Key and avg for each key. I need to calculate at what percentile the average lies on for each key in Pyspark.

How do I replicate the same output for each key.

Was able to do the same in excel using PERCENTRANK.INC function. Output given below -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcxUk.png)

Note - Have more than a thousand keys in the data so need to automate it.

Comment: Please add whatever you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).